# Why does my Heroku-deployed React Application only work on Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku

I am currently having an issue with my React Application not working on any other browser other than Chrome. The Javascript loads just fine with no errors on Chrome and the application is currently fully deployed on Heroku (link: https://weathrd.herokuapp.com/).

In regards to my application, I have a search query set up in the "overview.js" component that creates a "get" request, with a parameter passed in that gets fed into the weather api I am using. Then, I retrieve the json information from the "/forecast" page and feed that back into "overview.js" to display on the screen.

I do not have any regex notation within any of my code, so I don't think that would be an issue here. I also have fully updated my Heroku deploy code and I do not think there is some sort of confusion on Heroku? Regardless, here is my server code, overview component code, and the error I am receiving on Safari:

server code:

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const axios = require('axios');

require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.use(express.static("public"))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json('hi');
});

app.get('/forecast', (req, res) => {   
    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: `http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?`,
        params: {
            q: req.query.city,
            key : process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
            days: '3',
            api: 'no',
            alerts: 'no',
        }, 
    };

    axios.request(options).then((response) => {
        res.json(response.data);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on http://localhost:${PORT} `))
```

Safari Error:
[image]

The error also mentions the component from which I am making the API request from "overview.js", so here is that code also:

overview.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './overview.css';
import { RecentSearches } from '../Recent Searches/recentSearches';
import { Hourly } from '../Hourly/hourly';
import { Fiveday } from '../5 Day Forecast/fiveday';
import 'animate.css';

const axios = require('axios'); 

export function Overview() {
    const [forecast, setForecast] = useState(null);

    // this callback function receives the searched city entered from recentSearches and applies it to fetchForecast
    const getSearch = (searchedCity) => {
        fetchForecast(searchedCity);
    }; 

    async function fetchForecast(searchedCity) {

        const options = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://weathrd.herokuapp.com/forecast',
            params: {city: searchedCity}
        };

        axios.request(options).then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);
            setForecast(response.data);
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
        
    };  
    
    return (
        <div>
            <div className='jumbotron' id='heading-title'>
                <h1>Welcome to <strong>Weathered</strong>!</h1>
                <h3>A Simple Weather Dashboard </h3>
            </div>

            <div className='container-fluid' id='homepage-skeleton'>
                <div className='d-flex' id='center-page'>
                    <RecentSearches getSearch={getSearch}/>

                    <Hourly forecast={forecast}/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <Fiveday forecast={forecast}/>        
        </div>
    )
};
```

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: The error message is fairly clear: these browsers refuse to include insecure (HTTP) content on a secure (HTTPS) page, as it can compromise the security of that page.

Comment: (Also, you probably don't want it accessing `http://localhost/` at all anyways, as it's not going to work for anyone except you that way.)

Comment: Ahh, I just realized my error... I completely forgot to update my build. So it was running my old development requests. Thanks for the help!